# #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) MAMP MySQL access denied

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mamp, mysql-error-1045

I'm trying to copy a live WordPress site to my local server. I went to import the database from the live site through MAMP, and I received an error message when trying to connect to phpMyAdmin:

**#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

I have a couple local WP installations running already, and I'm able to access them through the localhost:8888/sitename path just fine.

I haven't changed any passwords or messed around with any configurations in phpMyAdmin. In fact, it was all working fine just yesterday. I had to re-boot my computer because it froze on me this morning, and that's when the issues began.

I even went into the config.inc.php file in Applications/MAMP/phpMyAdmin, and the usernames and passwords match what I had originally. (It definitely wasn't 'YES')

I'm stumped at this point. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try resetting the MySQL server password using this [guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html).
Then put the new password in the PHPMyAdmin config?

**using password: YES** Means that you attempted to login using a password, not that the password used is 'YES' Its referring to the different options for logins like certificates etc.

Comment: Would I use the generic instructions from the MySQL guide you sent? I'm using OSX.

Comment: Yes, MAMP still is just a plain old MySQL server behind the scenes, Does anything else connect to this database using the root account? because if you reset it keep in mind you will need to update the password in any other configs that connect to this database. But from what you describe it sounds like a fresh install.

Comment: Hmm. I got the following error when entering "--skip-grant-tables" into terminal: `-bash: --skip-grant-tables: command not found`

Comment: That line is referencing starting the Mysql server with that flag, Not running it alone, I think they expect `mysql --skip-grant-tables`

Comment: Ok, I think I was able reset the root password using this tutorial: [link](http://www.tech-otaku.com/local-server/resetting-mamp-mysql-root-user-password/)

Comment: that got me into phpMyAdmin on my local server, so that's a plus. however, when I tried to navigate to one of my local WP sites through localhost:8888/testsite, I got an error establishing database connection.

Comment: You need to update the wp-config file with the database credentials as well, That should fix it.

Comment: I just edited the wp-config file and I'm still getting a database error. MAMP doesn't seem to want to connect to the MySQL server, but it is connected to Apache server. Could that be the issue?

Comment: It could be, There is a 2nd part to the guide you posted here: [link](http://www.tech-otaku.com/local-server/changing-mysql-root-user-password-mamp/#mamp-files-to-update) Try run through that to re-establish MAMPs access to the database aswell

Comment: I'm trying to get through step one of the tutorial, but I can't because the MySQL server won't start in MAMP: 
To change the MySQL password for root ensure that MAMP’s MySQL server is running then open Terminal and type the following, replacing NEWPASSWORD with the password of your choice:

Comment: Ignore that step, It assumes you want to change the password to a new one and that you know the old one at the start of the guide. You have already changed it so just continue on with updating the files he mentions

Comment: I'm not really sure what to enter into the terminal for each file. Do I enter `/Applications/MAMP/bin/checkMysql.sh *` into the terminal?

Comment: Nah you just need to open them in your favourite text editor "For files marked * an easy way to locate the old password is to search for the string -p" (Ignore the * stuff its just part of the article)

Comment: Ok, I went through every file it said to and the password matches what I just changed it to. Still not sure what the deal is.

Comment: Make sure every party of MAMP is restarted so it loads the new passwords from the files, Try restart your machine? Can you tell me the error you are getting now is it still in MAMP?

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. And imported the database copy from the live site that started me down this path. Now I'm getting a 500 sever error when going to localhost8888:/testsite2. I think it has something to do with the htaccess doc. It didn't copy over when I pulled the live site files via ftp earlier. Not sure though...

Comment: Yea it could be htaccess or A php config issue. Try get the file and compare it to your test site.

Comment: @user3870736 Did you have any luck?

Comment: Sorry! Just getting to this today. No luck yet. Everything looks good to go in the wp-config.php file. I pulled the htaccess file from the live site via FTP and put in the local directory, but it's not showing up at all, and I'm still getting the 500 internal server error when navigating to localhost:8888/testsite2

Comment: Ok, I just turned debug on and got this error:`Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in /Users/labedzde/Documents/Sites/pitchdesignunion/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/lib/W3/Cache/Memcached.php on line 38`

Comment: You just need to fix the plug in or disable it. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/memcached-issue-after-migrating-site

Answer (score 0):

Try to use single quotes in password, cause the symbol $ inside double quotes is like aphp variable

Answer (score -2):

change the password to a more basic form. for example i had "!@#$]#$%^%&^" i changed it to "mypassword1" and it worked. It is a wordpress issues that it doesn't support weird characters.

Comment: you must be retarded to use those passwords. I made them up. What I am trying to say is that... using a password with complex chars made my wordpress not to connect to the database. So I changed the password to a more simpler form and it worked. I am running a local installation of worpress just for testing purposes. You must test what chars your wordpress can use to connect. Anyways that was my solution to my problem and it fixed it. I hope it works for all of you too.